# How to get exact value from querystring in controller or javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, query-string, url-encoding

I want to exact value from queryString in controller or JavaScript

I am passing this param in querystring `6fmqW+UIk9ArzwWPIwK9E9DF6oYEOsu+G3DMVZWefMKGWcszbvIlmsmG7X4Y6jCLcIFPHfUQrZTPNhKdOxb5xg==`

And in controller getting like this

```
6fmqW UIk9ArzwWPIwK9E9DF6oYEOsu G3DMVZWefMKGWcszbvIlmsmG7X4Y6jCLcIFPHfUQrZTPNhKdOxb5xg==
```

Then I am getting error when going to decrypt my param.

I have try to encode using this code

```
var str = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Request.QueryString["param"]);
```

original is:

```
/q1t7q8UJ2ad/8NG5kCLm1ovilWVYe7BpsHtapcs5GcA9OcrqCPcDGjmbcKrC3Gjz5b4LRbAc9ibj2gG4o1IeQ==
```

Above code return like this

```
%2fq1t7q8UJ2ad%2f8NG5kCLm1ovilWVYe7BpsHtapcs5GcA9OcrqCPcDGjmbcKrC3Gjz5b4LRbAc9ibj2gG4o1IeQ%3d%3d
```

How to get exact value from queryString?

Your answer will appreciable!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error i got in my decrypt method: invalid string

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

When we generate encrpyt string at the same time we need to use below code then pass into query string param

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode()
```